# Why would an Entity Framework model generator not create code for a table when I selected it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I have **Visual Studio 2008**:

- I can create Entity Framework models on **existing tables** in a SQL Server **2005** database.
- I can create Entity Framework models on **tables I create** in a local SQL Server **2008** database files.

However, when I **add a new table** to the SQL Server **2005** database, then try to create an Entity Framework model on it, it **lets me click** the little checkbox next to the table and finish, but the **.edmx/...Designer.cs file** consists only of four methods but **nothing about the table** that I selected, as if the I hadn't selected it.

- **What could be causing code not to be generated on the table I selected?**
- **Where could I look for error messages regarding the attempted creation of code for this table?**

Answer (score 1):

0) I think, you have added and then deleted this table before. In this case you should open model file (Designer.cs), remove all this table related records (manualy) and then refresh the model.

1) Maybe you have many-to-many relationship tables. EF decides no to add "link" table in this case.

2) Maybe you have a table that has two fields (PK and FK to other one) ONLY. In this case EF does the same.

3) Install later SP to VS and framework.

4) Check connection string.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't even work for the simplest of tables, e.g. Id (PK), FirstName varchar(50), LastName FirstName varchar(50)

Comment: I think, you have deleted this table before. In this case you should open model file, remove all this table related records (manualy) and then refresh the model.

Comment: it's odd because it's a new database and new table: I can only imagine it has some kind of permission problem which allows it to show the table in the list, but not get its schema, etc.

Comment: update: when I add a new table to an existing database, then it works, so it seems that there is some kind of setting in the new database that I created that I am not making which causes Entity Framework to not generate classes for any tables inside that database even after you check them to be included in the model

Comment: Yes you are right. You can check the new one in the list of tables (those your model have not). EF does not automatically add new ones. And it is ok. Your model is not a snapshort of all tables. You can use some tables or views or don't. (if I understood you).